# Tree View hierarquico Dinamico C#

Tags: c#, winforms, view, treeview

Tenho a seguinte situação, meu select me retorna 3 campos **micro** (filho), **descr**(descr do filho) e **macro**(pai) os campos micro e macros são inteiros e podem ser qualquer numero não seguindo padrão (quando digo padrão me refiro a por exemplo o micro 2 não necessariamente tem o 1 como macro pode ser o 3) e eu preciso preencher um `treeview` com essas informações, eu consigo fazer minha consulta me retornar os registros nas ordens em que tem ser adicionados.

Minha tabela no banco de dados tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
ID_HIERARQUIA NUMBER    
MICRO NUMBER    
DESCR VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)    
MACRO NUMBER    
POSICAO VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
```

Utilizei esses `insert`'s para teste:

```
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM 
HIERARQUIA),'08','EQUIPAMENTO 08','','01');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'04','EQUIPAMENTO 04','08','0101');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'02','EQUIPAMENTO 02','04','010101');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'03','EQUIPAMENTO 03','04','010102');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'05','EQUIPAMENTO 05','08','0102');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'06','EQUIPAMENTO 06','05','010201');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'07','EQUIPAMENTO 07','05','010202');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'01','EQUIPAMENTO 01','07','01020201');    
INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA VALUES((SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_HIERARQUIA)+1,1) FROM HIERARQUIA),'09','EQUIPAMENTO 09','07','01020202');
```

Tentei a solução desse [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/7998a65e-8380-42e6-8dcf-8245451c855b/treeview-recursivo-com-c?forum=vscsharppt)

Onde ele alimenta a lista dele, eu adaptei para receber a seguinte query `SELECT MICRO, DESCR, MACRO FROM HIERARQUIA  ORDER BY POSICAO`

Mas apesar de alimentar de forma correta ele só cria o primeiro node e não adiciona nem mesmo os filhos dele, se vocês puderem me ajudar fico grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vai custa uma nota...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ExemploTreeView.aspx.cs"
  Inherits="WebApplication1tiraduvidas.ExemploTreeView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TreeView ID="tvMenu" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" CssClass="TView" PopulateNodesFromClient="false"
      ShowExpandCollapse="true" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"
      SkipLinkText="" NodeStyle-CssClass="Node" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="NodeSel"
      HoverNodeStyle-CssClass="NodeHover">
      <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/folder.png" />
      <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/folder.png" />
      <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/folder.png" />
    </asp:TreeView>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1tiraduvidas
{
    public partial class ExemploTreeView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string myConnString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Teste;User ID=sa;Password=teste";
            }
        }

        private DataTable m_HIERARQUIA = null;
        private DataTable HIERARQUIA_
        {
            get
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "select micro, macro, DESCR from HIERARQUIA order by POSICAO";

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    conn.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    conn.Close();
                    m_HIERARQUIA = dt;
                }
                catch (Exception Exc)
                {
                }
                return m_HIERARQUIA;

            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] parents = HIERARQUIA_.Select("[macro] is null");

            Int32 IdPai = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in parents)
            {
                IdPai = (Int32)dr["micro"];
            }

            PopulateNodes(parents, tvMenu.Nodes, IdPai);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fluxos"></param>
        /// <param name="node"></param>
        /// <param name="micro_"></param>
        private void PopulateNodes(DataRow[] fluxos, TreeNodeCollection node, Int32 micro_)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in fluxos)
            {
                TreeNode Node = new TreeNode();
                Node.Text = dr["DESCR"].ToString();
                Node.Value = dr["micro"].ToString();
                Node.ImageUrl = "~/Images/folder.png";
                node.Add(Node);

                DataRow[] Filhos = HIERARQUIA_
                    .Select("[macro] =" + dr["micro"]);

                if (Filhos.Length > 0)                       // Recursivo !!
                    PopulateNodes(Filhos, Node.ChildNodes, micro_);

                // É o selecionado ?
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["micro"]) == micro_)
                {
                    Node.Selected = true;       // Seleciona e mostra eventuais filhos
                    Node.Expand();

                    TreeNode Pai = Node.Parent;      // Expande os pais
                    while (Pai != null)
                    {
                        Pai.Expand();
                        Pai = Pai.Parent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void tvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] parents = HIERARQUIA_.Select("[macro] is null");
            Int32 IdNode = Convert.ToInt32(tvMenu.SelectedNode.Value);
            tvMenu.Nodes.Clear();
            PopulateNodes(parents, tvMenu.Nodes, IdNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Banco

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HIERARQUIA](
    [ID_HIERARQUIA] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MICRO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCR] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [MACRO] [int] NULL,
    [POSICAO] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_HIERARQUIA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_HIERARQUIA] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO HIERARQUIA  ([MICRO],[DESCR],[MACRO],[POSICAO]) VALUES
 (1,'EQUIPAMENTO 08', null,'01')
,(2,'EQUIPAMENTO 04', 1,'0101')
,(3,'EQUIPAMENTO 02', 1,'010101')
,(4,'EQUIPAMENTO 03', 1,'010102')
,(5,'EQUIPAMENTO 05', 2,'0102')
,(6,'EQUIPAMENTO 06', 2,'010201')
,(7,'EQUIPAMENTO 07', 2,'010202')
,(8,'EQUIPAMENTO 01', 5,'01020201')
,(9,'EQUIPAMENTO 09', 5,'01020202')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou tentar adaptar aqui, esqueci de informar que era Windows Forms.. obrigado !!!

Comment: A ideia é a mesma só se atentar para o método PopulateNodes, esse você não precisa mudar.